# Not able to inject ViewModel with dagger2 android java

Tags: java, android, mvvm, dagger-2, android-architecture-components

I am trying to inject **viewmodel** with help of a common **ViewModelProviderFactory** in **dagger2**. (This is my first app with dagger and architecure components) This is the error i get when i build the code.

> Error:(26, 10) error: java.util.Map,javax.inject.Provider> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

[image]

Here is the code i use

**ViewModelProviderFactory**

```
@PerActivity

public class ViewModelProviderFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators;

    @Inject
    public ViewModelProviderFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators) {
        this.creators = creators;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
        Provider<? extends ViewModel> creator = creators.get(modelClass);
        if (creator == null) {
            for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> entry : creators.entrySet()) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.getKey())) {
                    creator = entry.getValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (creator == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass);
        }
        try {
            return (T) creator.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModelModule**

```
@Module
public abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(HomeViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindHomeViewModel(HomeViewModel homeViewModel);

    @Binds
    abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelProviderFactory factory);
}
```

**ApplicationComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, ViewModelModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void inject(BaseApp app);

    @ApplicationContext
    Context getContext();

    Application getApplication();

    WebService getWebService();

    PreferencesHandler getPreferencesHandler();

    InternetUtils getInternetUtils();
}
```

**ActivityComponent**

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = ActivityModule.class)
public interface ActivityComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

    void inject(SampleListActivity sampleListActivity);

    void inject(HomeActivity homeActivity);
}
```

**ViewModelKey**

```
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
public @interface ViewModelKey {
    Class<? extends ViewModel> value();
}
```

In my **activity** i use this code

```
@Inject
ViewModelProviderFactory mViewModelFactory;
........
oncreate(){
...
homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,mViewModelFactory).get(HomeViewModel.class);
.......
}
```

Comment: I am doing without factory. Take a look https://github.com/volkansahin45/Moneycim

Comment: Please include the full error message (the "stack" trace _after_ 'cannot be provided without [..]) Looks fine at a first glance

Comment: @DavidMedenjak updated the question. Added image of build error.

Comment: @VolkanSahin45 your approach creates a new unscoped instance of your `___ViewModel` each time your Activity/Fragment is re-created, aka it does not survive configuration change, and it does not receive `onCleared()` callback as it is not bound to a LifecycleOwner using `ViewModelProviders`. You may as well be not using AAC ViewModel, because it won't work the way it's expected to work. Using the framework incorrectly is not a solution ;)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I didn't know that. I will revert last changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ActivityComponent` is a `Component` (not a SubComponent) with a dependency on `ApplicationComponent`, so it has no access to the Map set up in the AppComponent.

Either switch to using a `SubComponent` for your `ActivityComponent`, or make sure to include a provision method for `Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>` in your AppComponent so that dependent components can access it.

```
interface AppComponent {
  // ..
  Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators();
}
```

Comment: You saved my day man. Works like a charm. Thank you so much (y)

Comment: I added Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators(); in my Application component class, and it started working.